# SEO/Keywords Monitoring service

Tags: seo, keywords, tracking, monitoring

Is there a good monitoring service for international sites?

I have sites in many countries and I would like to get some monitoring service to track the visibility in Google for all the domains and the most visited keywords and so on. I have found some, but most of them are handling only 3-4 markets, but I need to set a monitoring for each of my sites in many countries. Does anyone use such a service?

Comment: This question is not programming related and is therefore off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) provides a great deal of data on keywords. If you haven't tried it recently, take another look - it's free and it covers the requirements you listed.